# wp_title() returns 'page not found' on page 2

Tags: pagination, wp-title, pods-framework

I'm currently making a custom Wordpress template, and I'm using `paginate_link` to make page links at the bottom.

index.php

```
<?php

get_header();

?>
<div class="container">
  <div class="card-columns">
    <?php

    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

    $args1 = array(
      'post_type' => array('theory', 'tasks', 'tutorials', 'video', 'interactive'),
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'posts_per_page' => 10,
      'paged' => $paged
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args1 ); ?>

    <?php if( $query->have_posts() ): ?>

      <?php while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
      if (get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'external', true ))
      {
        $weblink = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'external', true );
      }
      else
      {
        $weblink = get_permalink();
      }
      ?>

      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-top"><?php
        $post_type = get_post_type_object( get_post_type($post) );
        echo strtoupper($post_type->labels->singular_name) . " ";
        ?>
      </div>
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( array(500,500, 'class'  => "card-img-top img-fluid") ); ?></a>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title"><a href="<?php echo $weblink ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> <?php
        if (get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'external', true ))
        {

          echo '<i class="material-icons">link</i>';
        } ?></h4>
        <p class="card-text"><?php
        if (get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'external', true ))
        {
          $kilde = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'source', true );
          echo 'External: ' . $source[name] . ".";
        } else {
          echo get_the_excerpt();
        } ?></p>
        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted"><?php
        $post_id = get_the_ID();
        $args = [
          'taxonomy'     => 'topic'
        ];
        $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post_id, $args ); foreach($terms as $term) {

          if ($term->parent == 0) //check for parent terms only
          echo " <a href='" . get_term_link($term, $args) ."'>" . $term->name . "</a>"; } ?></small></p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <?php
    endwhile;?>

    <div class="nav-previous alignleft"><?php
    $total_pages = $query->max_num_pages;

    if ($total_pages > 1){

      $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

      echo paginate_links(array(
        'base' => rtrim( get_pagenum_link( 1 ), '/' ) . '%_%',
        'format' => '/page/%#%',
        'current' => $current_page,
        'total' => $total_pages,
        'prev_text'    => __('« previous'),
        'next_text'    => __('next »'),
      ));
    }
    ?></div>



  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php

?>

</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

But when I go to any other pages (from page 2 and so on) the title will show "Page not found", but the content is there and pagination is working.

To show the title I'm using this in functions.php:

```
add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );

function site_wp_title( $title, $sep ) {
    global $paged, $page;

    if ( is_feed() )
        return $title;

    // Add the site name.
    $title .= get_bloginfo( 'name' );

    // Add the site description for the home/front page.
    $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
    if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )
        $title = "$title $sep $site_description";

    // Add a page number if necessary.
    if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 )
        $title = "$title $sep " . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'it' ), max( $paged, $page ) );

    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'site_wp_title', 10, 2 );
```

It seems like that `wp_title()` doesn't get its results from the custom `wp_query()`, cause it works with native posts.

Comment: First, are you *not* using the [`title-tag` feature](https://codex.wordpress.org/Title_Tag)? Second, I tried your code on a Page (post type `page`) and `wp_title()` doesn't include "not found". And you should use `rtrim( get_pagenum_link( 1 ), '/' )` to remove the extra slash.

Comment: What is `$query`? Is it your custom query? Where and how do you use it?

Comment: @SallyCJ I'm using it now. Problem is still there though.

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż Yes, it's a custom query. I have added it to my questions now. Hope it helps.

Comment: Are you using the code on a Page (`example.com/page-slug/`)? Because as I've said, I'm not getting the problem. And have you tried deactivating all plugins? Or try `var_dump( $GLOBALS['wp']->query_vars, $GLOBALS['wp']->matched_query )` (e.g. add it after `get_header()` in the template) and share/inspect the dump output.

Comment: @SallyCJ On page 2 it returns `array(1) { ["paged"]=> string(1) "2" } string(8) "&paged=2"`.

Comment: I managed to narrow it down to some problems with the custom post types. Cause if I add some native post types, and remove `post_type` from arguments, it works fine.

Comment: Well, the query is obviously missing the page slug (e.g. `pagename=page-slug`) *if* you're indeed using the code on a Page. And if you haven't, try deactivating the PODS plugin..?

Comment: @SallyCJ It's not on a Page, but it's on page 2... in blog posts (index). Good advice on deactivating PODS, but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: @SallyCJ It seems to work if I remove the `post_type` argument in my query. So it works on native Wordpress post. It seems like the title is based on just a query for native posts, and not my custom `wp_query()`.

Comment: Can you show the full code in your custom template? And are you actually calling `wp_title()` somewhere after your custom query? Did you mean to use `the_title()` instead?..

Comment: @SallyCJ I added the `index.php` and my functions for showing title (not using `wp_title()` anymore). It seems like that the title doesn't get its results from the custom `wp_query()`, cause it works with native posts. Like if title is loaded before the `wp_query()`.

Comment: @SallyCJ But the problem seem to be that the `wp_query()` and the title tag doesn't fetch same content. If I add 3 native posts (and a lot of custom posts), and set 1 post per page (pagination), each page (pagination) has the title in the format "[blogname] - Page [page number]". But any other pages (pagination) will get "Page not found - [blogname]" as a title after page 3 (the number of native blog posts).

Comment: @SallyCJ Found the error, and answered my own questions. It helped write my thoughts and discuss it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the title was fetched before the query, and therefore didn't fetch the custom posts. Had to add a `pre_get_posts` to my `functions.php` to make it work:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts' );

function my_get_posts( $query ) {

    if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
        $query->set( 'post_type', array('theory', 'tasks', 'tutorials', 'video', 'interactive') );

    return $query;
}
```